# How to loop through the shapes based on values in different tables?

Tags: excel, vba

as stated above I want to loop through different shape names and hide them based on values in particular cells. I did the normal `If Else` method but I want to shorted the code so that it loops through all the cells in the specified sheet. The code that I used is as follows:

```
Sub L0worksheet_change()

    Dim Target As Range
    Dim L0 As Worksheet
    Dim WBPT As Workbook

    Set WBPT = Workbooks("Progress_Tables.xlsm")
    Set L0 = WBPT.Worksheets("L0_ProgressT")
    Set Target = L0.Range("G4")
    If Target < Range("L4") Then
        Shapes.Range(Array("Arrow: Down 1")).Visible = msoCTrue
        Shapes.Range(Array("Arrow: Right 2")).Visible = msoCFalse
        Shapes.Range(Array("Arrow: Up 3")).Visible = msoCFalse
    Else
        If Target > Range("F4") Then
            Shapes.Range(Array("Arrow: Down 1")).Visible = msoCFalse
            Shapes.Range(Array("Arrow: Right 2")).Visible = msoCFalse
            Shapes.Range(Array("Arrow: Up 3")).Visible = msoCTrue
        Else
            If Target > Range("L4") & Target < Range("F4") Then
                Shapes.Range(Array("Arrow: Down 1")).Visible = msoCFalse
                Shapes.Range(Array("Arrow: Right 2")).Visible = msoCTrue
                Shapes.Range(Array("Arrow: Up 3")).Visible = msoCFalse
            Else
                Shapes.Range(Array("Arrow: Down 1")).Visible = msoCFalse
                Shapes.Range(Array("Arrow: Right 2")).Visible = msoCFalse
                Shapes.Range(Array("Arrow: Up 3")).Visible = msoCFalse
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Set Target = Nothing


    Set Target = Range("G5")
    If Target < Range("L5") Then
        Shapes.Range(Array("MiRed")).Visible = msoCTrue
        Shapes.Range(Array("MiAmber")).Visible = msoCFalse
        Shapes.Range(Array("MiGreen")).Visible = msoCFalse
    Else
        If Target > Range("F5") Then
            Shapes.Range(Array("MiRed")).Visible = msoCFalse
            Shapes.Range(Array("MiAmber")).Visible = msoCFalse
            Shapes.Range(Array("MiGreen")).Visible = msoCTrue
        Else
            If Target > Range("L5") & Target < Range("F5") Then
                Shapes.Range(Array("MiRed")).Visible = msoCFalse
                Shapes.Range(Array("MiAmber")).Visible = msoCTrue
                Shapes.Range(Array("MiGreen")).Visible = msoCFalse
            Else
                Shapes.Range(Array("MiRed")).Visible = msoCFalse
                Shapes.Range(Array("MiAmber")).Visible = msoCFalse
                Shapes.Range(Array("MiGreen")).Visible = msoCFalse
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Set Target = Nothing

    Set Target = Range("G6")
    If Target < Range("L6") Then
        Shapes.Range(Array("RaRed")).Visible = msoCTrue
        Shapes.Range(Array("RaAmber")).Visible = msoCFalse
        Shapes.Range(Array("RaGreen")).Visible = msoCFalse
    Else
        If Target > Range("F6") Then
            Shapes.Range(Array("RaRed")).Visible = msoCFalse
            Shapes.Range(Array("RaAmber")).Visible = msoCFalse
            Shapes.Range(Array("RaGreen")).Visible = msoCTrue
        Else
            If Target > Range("L6") & Target < Range("F6") Then
                Shapes.Range(Array("RaRed")).Visible = msoCFalse
                Shapes.Range(Array("RaAmber")).Visible = msoCTrue
                Shapes.Range(Array("RaGreen")).Visible = msoCFalse
            Else
                Shapes.Range(Array("RaRed")).Visible = msoCFalse
                Shapes.Range(Array("RaAmber")).Visible = msoCFalse
                Shapes.Range(Array("RaGreen")).Visible = msoCFalse
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Set Target = Nothing

    Set Target = Range("G7")
    If Target < Range("L7") Then
        Shapes.Range(Array("MESRed")).Visible = msoCTrue
        Shapes.Range(Array("MESAmber")).Visible = msoCFalse
        Shapes.Range(Array("MESGreen")).Visible = msoCFalse
    Else
        If Target > Range("F7") Then
            Shapes.Range(Array("MESRed")).Visible = msoCFalse
            Shapes.Range(Array("MESAmber")).Visible = msoCFalse
            Shapes.Range(Array("MESGreen")).Visible = msoCTrue
        Else
            If Target > Range("L7") & Target < Range("F6") Then
                Shapes.Range(Array("MESRed")).Visible = msoCFalse
                Shapes.Range(Array("MESAmber")).Visible = msoCTrue
                Shapes.Range(Array("MESGreen")).Visible = msoCFalse
            Else
                Shapes.Range(Array("MESRed")).Visible = msoCFalse
                Shapes.Range(Array("MESAmber")).Visible = msoCFalse
                Shapes.Range(Array("MESGreen")).Visible = msoCFalse
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Set Target = Nothing

End Sub
```

Is there a way to make the code more efficient and hopefully shorten it?

Any help is really appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To perform the same action on multiple shapes at different places in you code, you can create an array that you can re-use multiple times:

```
'You can replace this:
Shapes.Range(Array("MESRed")).Visible = msoCFalse
Shapes.Range(Array("MESAmber")).Visible = msoCFalse
Shapes.Range(Array("MESGreen")).Visible = msoCFalse

'With this:
Dim ShapeNames() As Variant
ShapeNames = Array("MESRed", "MESAmber", "MESGreen")

Shapes.Range(ShapeNames).Visible = msoCFalse
```

Note: If you try this code inside a regular module instead of a sheet module, you'll need to specify the `Sheet` for the `Shapes` object (eg.: `Activesheet.Shapes`) and you should also specify the Sheet of the `Range` object.